# i want to add background color around some icon, i have added the html code and th epicture

Tags: css, svg, css-selectors, icons, background-color

```
    <img class="icon-document" src="/images/icon-document.svg" alt="icon-document">

    <img class="icon-folder" src="/images/icon-folder.svg" alt="icon-folder">

    <img class="icon-upload" src="/images/icon-upload.svg" alt="icon-upload">
    </div>
```

[this is the image of what I want to achieve**strong text**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZfOw.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raphael, it is either the icon image is already carrying the background-color, but if not then the icon would have to be png image with no background.

It is only when the image itself has no background that you can add background with CSS

Answer (score 0):

try to use font awesome icon. then you can easily set a background color.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply background color on that way. I would suggest three options:

1. Give a border radius to the image like this: `<img src="/images/icon-document.svg" alt="icon-document" style="border-radius: 50%;">`
2. You can crop the image with any editor or online [circle_crop_image](https://crop-circle.imageonline.co/) . Do the same with an image which contains only the color you want and add your image on top of that)
3. Find a similar icon on bootstrap